# Multiple On click event not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm a little confused in having two functions in the onClick and how to make it work correctly. It works when only using one function but when there's two the "getCustomerList()" no longer works. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the related code:

HTML:

```
<form name="registration" action="registration.html" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
...
...

<input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="buttonandchecks(); getCustomerList(); return false">
</form>
<h2>Customer Attributes:</h2> 
<br>
<h3> <span id ="currentList"></span>
</h3>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function buttonandchecks()
{
var x;
var output="";
var resultoutput="";
var extra=parseFloat(0);
var radio_value; 
var total=parseInt(0); 


        for(x=0;x<document.costEstimation.special.length;x++)
        {
        if(document.costEstimation.special[x].checked)
            {
             radio_value=document.costEstimation.special[x].value;
            }
        }

        radio_value=parseFloat(radio_value);


    if(document.costEstimation.AC.checked)
        {
        extra+=10;
        output=(output+" A/C");
        }
    if(document.costEstimation.WB.checked)
        {
        extra+=100;
        output=(output+" Brakes");
        }
    if(document.costEstimation.CC.checked)
        {
        extra+=20;
        output=(output+" Cruise Control");
        }
    if(document.costEstimation.BS.checked)
        {
        extra+=30;
        output=(output+" Baby Seat");
        }

total=radio_value+extra;
resultoutput=("Total: " + total.toFixed(2)+ " \nIncluding Extras: " + output);
alert(resultoutput);

}
 function getCustomerList () {

    var customer={Text1,Lname,Add,City,StPrv,Cntry,Hphn,Wphn};

    var i=0;
    var thisList="";

    customer.Text1=document.getElementById("Text1").value;
    customer.Lname=document.getElementById("Lname").value;
    customer.Add=document.getElementById("Add").value;
    customer.City=document.getElementById("City").value;
    customer.StPrv=document.getElementById("StPrv").value;
    customer.Cntry=document.getElementById("Cntry").value;
    customer.Hphn=document.getElementById("Hphn").value;
    customer.Wphn=document.getElementById("Wphn").value;


    customerList.push(customer);
        for(i=0; i< customerList.length;i++)
        {

        var thisCustomer={Text1,Lname,Add,City,StPrv,Cntry,Hphn,Wphn};
        thisCustomer=customerList[i];
        thisList+=thisCustomer.Text1 + " , "+thisCustomer.Lname+" , "+thisCustomer.Add+" , "+thisCustomer.City+" , "+thisCustomer.StPrv+" , "+thisCustomer.Cntry+" , "+thisCustomer.Hphn+" , "+thisCustomer.Wphn;
        thisList+="<br>";

        }

    document.getElementById("currentList").innerHTML=thisList;

}
```

Comment: Please define "no longer works". Notice also, that direct references to elements via `document` is deprecated in all browsers, and maybe obsoleted in some browsers.

Comment: `customer={Text1,Lname,Add,City,StPrv,Cntry,Hphn,Wphn};` that is invalid syntax, did you check your JS console for errors?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should call `getCustomerList();` from within your `buttonandchecks();` method. Something like this:

```
function formSubmit() {
    buttonandchecks();
    getCustomerList();
}
```